# Modern Windows Metafile alternative

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office, vector-graphics, wmf

What would be the modern way to generate vector graphics, that has to be inserted in Microsoft Office documents?

My aging application currently does this by making Enhanced Metafiles (.emf) in a temporary directory and inserting into Excel documents using automation. It works pretty good actually.

But the application needs a complete rewrite and technology rethink, so I'm wondering if this age old image format is still the best choice. Windows metafiles are basically a sequence of GDI function calls, and GDI is apparently obsolete, so it doesn't seem like it to me.

I looked at SVG, but its not supported in Office 2010, which is a requirement.

I just wonder, how is vector graphics *supposed* to be done in modern Windows platforms and Microsoft Office documents?

Comment: "EMF+" is the GDI+ update for EMF, no idea if Office supports EMF+ records.  Is there a specific capability your missing? if not, *if it ain't broke, don't fix it* can save some headaches.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out EMF+ / GDI+, though it seems to be just an extra enhanced metafile and not my sought after modern SVG like format for Windows. I guess it doesn't exist and best practise, or only practice, of embedding vector graphics in Office documents today is still good ol' metafiles.